# Find any (arbitrary) path between a pair of source-destination

Tags: oracle-graph

We are trying to write PGQL query on PG View(version 21.4) to find any (arbitrary) path between a pair of source-destination.

We had being using the following link as our PGQL guideline. https://pgql-lang.org/spec/1.4/#any-path

Query: `SELECT s.ID as s_id, d.ID AS d_id FROM MATCH ANY (s) -[e]->+ (d) on my_graph`

Error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Only zero (0) or more path quantifier is supported`

What would had cause the error since it was working on PGS.
Any solution or workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 21.4, only `*` is supported on PG Views. From 22.1, other quantifiers are also supported.

- Significant New Features in Oracle Graph Server and Client 22.1 https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/22.1/spgdg/changes-in-this-release.html

> Added PGQL support for more quantifiers when executing PGQL queries against property graph views.

- Supported Quantifiers in PGQL SELECT Queries https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/22.1/spgdg/pgql-features-supported-property-graph-views.html

```
Syntax  Description
------  -----------
*       zero or more
+       one or more
?       zero or one
{n}     exactly n
{n,}    n or more
{n,m}   between n and m (inclusive)
{,m}    between zero and m (inclusive)
```